# What is the equivalent of @ExceptionHandler in RSocket world please?

Tags: java, rsocket

Small question regarding how to have a "Controller" level `@ExceptionHandler`, but for RSocket, please.

A bit naive, I tried having a Controller level `ExceptionHandler` with the following in my RSocket application. (like in any other MVC/Webflux application)

```
    @ExceptionHandler
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> exception(final Exception exception) {
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(exception.getMessage()));
    }
```

And so far, I am not seeing this "catching" anything. As I keep seeing this strange error.

```
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
    at io.rsocket.util.ByteBufPayload.ensureAccessible(ByteBufPayload.java:208) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.util.ByteBufPayload.sliceData(ByteBufPayload.java:155) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.PayloadUtils.retainDataAndReleasePayload(PayloadUtils.java:54) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.annotation.support.MessagingRSocket.retainDataAndReleasePayload(MessagingRSocket.java:184) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
```

So I was wondering, am I doing it wrong, or maybe, RSocket does not support `@ExceptionHandler` and I need to go via another mechanism?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the equivalent is [**`MessageExceptionHandler`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/MessageExceptionHandler.html) if the `RSocket` is running over websockets.

> [***WebSockets Exception handling***](https://dimitr.im/websockets-spring-boot#exception-handling)
>
> *Just like regular Spring MVC, we can handle exceptions as well.
> However, **rather than using the @ExceptionHandler** annotation, we **now
> have to use the @MessageExceptionHandler** annotation.*

---

So something like this would work:

```
@MessageExceptionHandler
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> exception(final Exception exception) 
{
    return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                                    .body(exception.getMessage()));
}
```

---

*Note that **`RSocket`** is a protocol that works over WebSockets, but also with plain TCP, among others. In this specific case, seems like your RSocket is over WS, so `@MessageExceptionHandler` is the correct annotation (not for being rsocket, but for acting like a websocket). If running over TCP, you may have to use the old `@ExceptionHandler`.*

*****edit --** As Rossen's comment states, there's no such link between MessageExceptionHandler and the protocol in use, so just ignore the text above!.***

Comment: `@MessageExceptionHandler` is not tied to the protocol such as WebSocket or TCP. It is rather a companion annotation for use with `@MessageMapping` methods.

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev thanks for the note, I wasn't sure about that, not really an expert on spring. Thanks for clarifying this, will cut off that part to avoid confussion.

Comment: Additionally, to apply the handler globally for all the controllers, handlers should be moved to a separate class and `@ControllerAdvice` should be added on the class like we do in Spring MVC.

Comment: @ssasi Using `@ControllerAdvice` along with `@MessageExceptionHandler` does not register the message exception handlers, I tested it with Spring Webflux 5.3.30. And it seems that it won't be supported for now https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26636